# PHP regex fails, succeeds on Regex 101

Tags: php, regex

Stumped by this one O_o...

```
if(preg_match("(\d{1,2})\:(\d{2})", "5:00", $matches) == 1) echo "works";
else echo "don't work";
```

Will echo

```
don't work
```

But the same regex on Regex 101 seems to work fine: http://regex101.com/r/mW1dN9

Do I need a global flag or something?

Comment: (1) enable error reporting.... (2) well, I guess that solved itself (you forgot delimiters).

Comment: you're missing your delimiters.

Comment: Haha noob mistake on my part. Easy points for you guys.

Comment: Why does the regex need the delimiters? Why does it fail without them?

Answer (score 3):

Your regex pattern needs some delimiters.

```
if(preg_match("#(\d{1,2})\:(\d{2})#", "5:00", $matches) == 1) echo "works";
else echo "don't work";
```

Comment: cool that worked. Why exactly are the delimiters necessary?

Comment: If you need to use any flags (e.g., global, case-insensitive, etc.), the delimiters show the regexp engine where to find them in the string. They have to be there, even if you're not using flags.

Comment: They separate the pattern from the flags. If you were to place an i after the closing delimter, it would make the pattern case insensitive. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: so it sounds like a case of "that's just how it works"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your regular expression within delimiters:

```
if(preg_match("/(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})/", "5:00", $matches) == 1) echo "works";
else echo "don't work";
```

Also, you don't need to escape the `:`, but it works either way.